# C# generics: default non-null value for member

Tags: c#, generics

In this generic "class":

```
public class Param<ValueType>{
    public ValueType value;
}
```

When `ValueType` is `string` I want `value` to be non-null for all newly created instances of class without explicitly passing default value through constructor. In my scenario `ValueType` can only be `int`, `float`, `bool`, `string` or `struct` (that doesn't need to be enforced).

How can I do that?

When I try to do this:

```
public class Param<ValueType> where ValueType: new(){
    public ValueType value = new ValueType();
}
```

class stops accepting strings.

When I remove new() constraint, I can no longer use `new ValueType()` (obviously) and `value` is null for all new instances of `Param<string>`.

What can I do about it?

The reason why I want this to happen is because I have `.Equals()` defined which does `value.Equals(other.value)`, which causes exception to be thrown when `value` is null.

Comment: Is it an option to make `value` a property? you can always check if its null there..

Comment: @Sayse: Wouldn't that result in the same problem, though? I'll need default value which I won't be able to provide by calling constructor when `ValueType` is `string`. I might be missing something obvious, though.

Comment: Why not change the place where Equals is called to check for default value first?

Comment: @Stilgar: Tested it, it might work. I though comparison with null would require IEquatable/IComparable.

Comment: Use `Object.Equals(a, b)` instead of `a.Equals(b)`, then you can avoid the null problem there, also a simple `if`-statement around your call to `Equals` would solve that problem.

Comment: @SigTerm - Yes I think I misread what you were trying to do, the same concept would work to check if its a string but then that is the same as xanatos' answer

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: That's also a good idea.  I think I'll go with `default` and switch to `Object.Equals`. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

```
public class Param<ValueType>
{
    public ValueType value = typeof(ValueType) == typeof(string) ? (ValueType)(object)string.Empty : default(ValueType);
}
```

note that `default(int) == 0` and so on.

Ah and for the comparison, you should:

```
bool areEqual = EqualityComparer<ValueType>.Equals(value, other.Value);
```

It correctly works for `null` values.

Note even that with generics, this:

```
if (value == null)
{

}
```

is perfectly valid code. Clearly it will be true only if `ValueType` can be `null` and is `null` (so for `ValueType == int` it won't ever happen)

Comment: Also, you could move the default value generation to a static class (say `internal static class DefaultParamValue<ValueType> { public static readonly ValueType Value = typeof(ValueType) == typeof(string)....`) so each instantiation of a `Param<ValueType>` avoids all the heavy work. (the default type evaluation is done only once per type) Then it just looks like `public class Param<ValueType> { public ValueType value = DefaultParamValue<ValueType>.Value; }` Even throw in some runtime type checking in `DefaultParamValue`'s static constructor to restrict usage to those desired special types.

Comment: "is perfectly valid code." My code was trying to call `value.Equals` which is a problem when `value == null`. Marking your answer as accepted. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair You don't really need another class: `private static readonly ValueType DefaultValue = typeof(ValueType) == typeof(string) ? (ValueType)(object)string.Empty : default(ValueType); public ValueType Value = DefaultValue;`.